# how to make staggered array out of a for loop javafx

Tags: for-loop, multidimensional-array, javafx

Can I get some help with this project I am trying to make a 9x9 of ellipsis in javafx. I have the code for the ellipsis but I can't figure out the logic to make the following happen.

Example of what I am looking for

[image]

I have used the regular for loop that just gives me 9x9. ellipsis stacked on top of one another

```
      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
```

so what do I have to do to this for loop, to make it look like the picture above
any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.. so I will only hint that you will need twice the size for you width. As you have a empty / space needed. Then look into the modulus operator..

Comment: dude it is really not a homework question its like 3 days from Christmas lol. i just really struggle with the logic behind them.. i am new to javafx i am making a board game the last question i asked was to advanced for me so i came up with an easier way. witch is to grid the GUI with the staggered array of ellipsis 9x9. Then behind it make a polygon shape fit the ellipsis.

Comment: This looks like `(5+4) x 2`, not `9x9`

Comment: sorry i was to lazy to draw out all the ellipsis?? so i suppose the top line would be 9 the second line would be 8 and so on 9 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just determine the horizontal/vertical offset of the circles.

Every other row contains one more circle and starts half of the offset further to the left than the smaller rows.

```
final double fieldWidth = 50;
final double fieldHeight = 50;
final double radius = 20;

Pane parent = new Pane();

boolean bigRow = true;
final int rows = 9;
final int columns = 9;
for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++, bigRow = !bigRow) {
    double offsetX = bigRow ? fieldWidth / 2 : fieldWidth;
    double offsetY = fieldHeight * y + fieldHeight / 2;
    for (int x = 0, size = bigRow ? columns : columns - 1; x < size; x++) {
        Circle c = new Circle(offsetX + x * fieldWidth, offsetY, radius, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        c.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        parent.getChildren().add(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: fabian thanks AGAIN for the help man your one of a few on this site that just answer questions, and explain them really well.. just on the question above i actually initialized [9][9] array in my code is it possible to use what code with an array rather then creating variables..

Comment: @enat If you like the answer, you should probably mark it as correct. You might like to go back and mark some answers to your other questions as correct too. Not giving credit for answers will generally deter people from answering your questions in the future.

Comment: thanks james_D i thought i had done so. but if it dose not work do you still mark it as correct??

Comment: @enat See [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). There are quite a few [help pages on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) that you might find generally useful. (In this case, though, the answer clearly does work.)